# Cannot use go shared library in my python file

Tags: python, python-3.x, go, shared-libraries, ctypes

I have a file called `main.go` which defines a function called `test`.
I would like to be able to call this function from my python script.

**main.go**

```
package main

import "C"

// export test
func test() int {
    return 1
}

func main() {}
```

compiled with :
`go build -o lib.so -buildmode=c-shared main.go`

**main.py**

```
import ctypes

mylib = ctypes.CDLL("./lib.so")


result = mylib.test()


print(result)
```

when i run the python program i get this error:
`AttributeError: ./lib.so: undefined symbol: test`

What am i missing ?

Go version
`go version go1.21.3 linux/amd64`

Python Version:
`Python 3.10.12`

I tried updating Go (previously I had version 1.21.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is correct except `// export`
there is an extra space that creates the problem

```
package main

import "C"

//export test      <------ remove the extra space here
func test() int {
    return 1
}

func main() {}
```

```
python main.py
```

Output:

```
1
```

Comment: That fix the issue. Thank you!!